# value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

Tags: scala, generics, apache-spark, rdd, traits

It's very sad.My spark version is 2.1.1,Scala version is 2.11

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import com.mufu.wcsa.component.dimension.{DimensionKey, KeyTrait}
import com.mufu.wcsa.log.LogRecord
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object PV {

//
  def stat[C <: LogRecord,K <:DimensionKey](statTrait: KeyTrait[C ,K],logRecords: RDD[C]): RDD[(K,Int)] = {
    val t = logRecords.map(record =>(statTrait.getKey(record),1)).reduceByKey((x,y) => x + y)
```

I got this error

```
at 1502387780429
[ERROR] /Users/lemanli/work/project/newcma/wcsa/wcsa_my/wcsavistor/src/main/scala/com/mufu/wcsa/component/stat/PV.scala:25: error: value reduceByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(K, Int)]
[ERROR]     val t = logRecords.map(record =>(statTrait.getKey(record),1)).reduceByKey((x,y) => x + y)
```

there is defined a trait

```
trait KeyTrait[C <: LogRecord,K <: DimensionKey]{
  def getKey(c:C):K
}
```

> It is compiled,Thanks.

```
 def stat[C <: LogRecord,K <:DimensionKey : ClassTag : Ordering](statTrait: KeyTrait[C ,K],logRecords: RDD[C]): RDD[(K,Int)] = {
    val t = logRecords.map(record =>(statTrait.getKey(record),1)).reduceByKey((x,y) => x + y)
```

Key need to override Ordering[T].

```
  object ClientStat extends KeyTrait[DetailLogRecord, ClientStat] {
      implicit val c

lientStatSorting = new Ordering[ClientStat] {
    override def compare(x: ClientStat, y: ClientStat): Int = x.key.compare(y.key)
  }

      def getKey(detailLogRecord: DetailLogRecord): ClientStat = new ClientStat(detailLogRecord)
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This comes from using a pair rdd function generically. The `reduceByKey` method is actually a method of the `PairRDDFunctions` class, which has an implicit conversion from `RDD`:

```
implicit def rddToPairRDDFunctions[K, V](rdd: RDD[(K, V)])
    (implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V], ord: Ordering[K] = null): PairRDDFunctions[K, V]
```

So it requires several implicit typeclasses. Normally when working with simple concrete types, those are already in scope. But you should be able to amend your method to also require those same implicits:

```
def stat[C <: LogRecord,K <:DimensionKey](statTrait: KeyTrait[C ,K],logRecords: RDD[C])(implicit kt: ClassTag[K], ord: Ordering[K])
```

Or using the newer syntax:

```
def stat[C <: LogRecord,K <:DimensionKey : ClassTag : Ordering](statTrait: KeyTrait[C ,K],logRecords: RDD[C])
```

Answer (score 5):

`reduceByKey` is a method that is only defined on RDDs of tuples, i.e. `RDD[(K, V)]` (K, V is just a convention to say that first is key second is value).

Not sure from the example about what you are trying to achieve, but for sure you need to convert the values inside the RDD to tuples of two values.